# Can't run git project in eclipse after clone

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I've been following this guide to set up a git environment in eclipse for a java project, but I could not get rid of this error.

I've been **able to set up a repository** on (hope i can write it) GitHub and push a project with EGit plugin for eclipse juno.

Then I deleted the local project and did the clone procedure (this becouse it was supposed to be easier than associate a local project to the remote one).

I seemed to work, since i can now see the repository in repository view, and **I am able to perform all basic git commands** (always through gui, since i am on Windows and i am not used to this OS).

Then I Build the project and seems to works (there are some errors relative to other used projects and jars or library, but it has always worked and are not important), **until I Run and it does not work at all and the only thing it says is**

*Errore: impossibile trovare o caricare la classe principale myPackage.MyMainClass*

that in italian (why the hell error messages are localized???) roughly means

*Error: impossible to find or load main class myPackage.MyMainClass*

i belive the problem is related to git and classpath, since git projects are not stored inside workspace, they are in the git folder, and inside them no bin is present.

i don't even know now where are the .class supposed to be created, wether in the workspace or in git folder, neither i know what to write in the .classpath to link (if it is right) to the correct project location... since i have a lot of projects i should edit all of them?

edit:
same procedure on an mac-osx platform produced same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mypackage/MyClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage/MyClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

edit: 
some things from eclipse error log

```
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.6.0_43
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/jalone/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data /Users/jalone/programmazione/java/workspace2 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/jalone/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

Error
Fri Apr 26 17:04:32 CEST 2013
The project description file (.project) for 'TheNameOfTheProject' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored.
```

and this is weird since it is present, but obviously only in the git folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it somehow. Almost editing some random settings i ended up in

Right click on project > Run As > Run Configurations...

then in Source tab only Default folder was present, and i noticed tat my Project was present but with a weird path like /NameOfTheProject.
So i left it it as it was but i added again my project with 'Add...'

Then i run and everything worked fine. This is really weird, and i am trying to commit this setting at least, but i can't find in which file it's stored.

If someone else give me a better answer ill accept it happily.

Comment: I got this error:[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, ....

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you did not push your .classpath and .project files to github.  I am guessing that your projects no longer look like java projects to Eclipse.  In the project icon in the package explorer, do you see a little 'J' on it?  Also, do you see a package icon on your src folder?  If not, then you did not properly commit your project metadata files.

If this is the case, I'll explain an easy way to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, but of course i pushed the .classpath, .project and .settings/ file/folders, and it really is a java project, i have autocomplete, referenced projects and libraries are perfectly recognized and compile errors as well. :/

Comment: Also, then make sure that you have auto-build set to true Project -> Build automatically.  And have a look in your Eclipse error log. Post any errors here.

Comment: No, i cleaned, deactivated, rebuilded manually and rreset build automatically a dozen time, didnt work.

Comment: there are some errors in error log this is the most relevant i belive, the other are just about some network or gui configuration, i put it in question post edit.
thanks you very much for the help!

Comment: According to the error message, the .project file is missing.  Are you sure that it was committed into the git repo?  You will have to recreate it from outside of Eclipse.

Comment: yes, i am sure, its both present in repo on github
https://github.com/jalone87/net.jalone.aiman/tree/master/AiMan
and in project :/ but i repeat, the project folder does not exists in workspace. there must be something to do with this, it's only present in git folder outside workspace (as forced to by by all best practices)